# Battery indicator can't refresh battery state

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a samsung np550p5c series laptop. I'm running a win7-ubuntu dual boot which I've recently set up. And my small problem is as follows:

The battery indicators in both OSs seem to be unaware of the situation my battery is in. They can't tell if it's plugged in or not. For example at like 10% I plug my laptop in, the charging LED on the laptop goes red(which is expected), power level starts rising as it is supposed to. However, my laptop has no idea that is charging. It can measure remaning power and time properly but it just doesn't know that it's charging. The same goes the other way around as well, the laptop may think it's charging but actually it's unplugged...

I've been looking for a solution but I've never anything like the situation like this on the Internet, so here I am!

PLEASE NOTE! My laptop IS charging and it doesn't take too long to charge and a fully charged battery can still last 3-4 hours which is the way it has always been. So I really think my battery is fine, just my laptop can't read the situation...

Comment: Is the laptop at the latest BIOS update?

Comment: I can't tell... Device manager says it's up-to-date but Samsung's software update thingy says it's not. And when I try to update it, nothing really happens. The installation progress bar doesn't even move

Comment: some playing around and using another 3rd party program got me the BIOS update and now it seems to be working properly.

Comment: Updating BIOS often fixes or resets hardware level issues like battery indications and charging. Glad that helped. Please add your own answer below to explain in detail what you did so if someone else searches for the same issue they can use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your battery needs to be calibrated. This is done in the BIOS. It will completely discharge the battery and reset the computers battery monitoring. It's easy, but takes 3 to 4 hours. So do not plan to use the laptop for that time.

To see a video explaining how to do this, go to [Samsumg's Support Site](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP550P5C-T01US), type battery calibration in the search box, then select "How-to Video" in the filter on the left.

Comment: I see a lot of people on the internet trying to fix everything with a calibration when it clearly isn't the real solution. I appreciate your taking time to write an answer but please, read the whole question. I said its performance was great. It didn't need a calibration. And the problem is solved without making my laptop unavailable for a long time.

Comment: Don't talk down to those who are trying to help you. I posted my answer with the information given before you commented you had resolved it yourself. This answer may not "exactly" match your issue, but it is a resolution for when the charge indicator doesn't match battery state.